# How can I get presenter view when recording my PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I am rehearsing towards a presentation using Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 on a Win8.1 machine using dual monitors (one for the slides, and one for my notes using presenter view) . I would like to record my narration per slide - I found the option to do so by:
`Slide Show Tab -> Record Slide Show` option.

The problem is, that while doing so I cant see the presenter comments on my secondary screen, which would usually pop-up while I'm presenting. Couldn't find any way to make it appear.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please vote here guys: https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/17420167-see-notes-while-narrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround I employed recently was to make two copies of the presentation, record on one and use the other one to see the notes. You have to move to the next slide manually in the notes presentation when you advance, which is extra work, but it is doable.

Comment: You say "workaround". Does that mean that there is no actual answer on how to do what the OP asked? (I have the same problem as you might imagine).

Comment: Didn't get it. Can you add more detail about your work around?